# java AES encryption then decrypt in PHP using same Key and IV

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, aes

I follow this guide [AES encryption on Java side - decryption on PHP side and selecting a single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036826/aes-encryption-on-java-side-decryption-on-php-side-and-selecting-a-single-key?rq=1) but the accepted answer is not really working. I even hardcoded the KEY and IV values in java so that i am sure that i have the same values in PHP.

```
private static final byte[] keyValue =
        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
                'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

private static final byte[] ivValue =
        new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                '7', '8', '9', '0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

JAVA (key) generation:

```
String ALGO = "AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding";
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
```

JAVA (iv) generation:

```
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivValue);
```

Then i use it to Encrypt / Decrypt in JAVA like this:

```
  //ENCRYPTION
  String encrypted = encrypt("Hello World!",key,ivSpec);

  //DECRYPTION
  String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted,key,ivSpec);

public static String encrypt(String Data, Key key, IvParameterSpec ivSpec) throws Exception {

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);       
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());     
    String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return encryptedValue;
}


public static String decrypt(String encryptedData, Key key, IvParameterSpec ivSpec) throws Exception {

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);   
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData,Base64.NO_WRAP);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

NOW, in PHP i get the encrypted value thru POST and i hardcoded the KEY and IV value:

```
$encrypted = $_POST["encrypted"];
$key = "TheBestSecretKey";
$iv = "0123456789012345";

$decrypted = decryptMessage($encrypted,$key,$iv);

function decryptMessage($encrypted,$key,$iv)
{
   $ivNum = (int)$iv;
   $ivIn = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), $ivNum);
   $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $ivIn);
}
```

Encrypted Message: TXCv3f+r+h71y/NzCk08Hw==

Expected Result of (decrypted) variable: "Hellow World!"

Current Result of (decrypted) variable: �@����6�I��Ԗmݕ����WMu

Is there any other workaround to achieve my expected result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: If you provided the encrypted data as hex (yes hex, because not all bytes are printable characters) it could be checked. (Displaying random bytes as characters doesn't work.) Suggestion: Add the encrypted data to the question.

Comment: I find `$ivNum = (int)$iv;` suspicious but then it has been decades since I used PHP.

Comment: @zaph, i already added the encrypted data. and thank you for the suggestion, i will consider using DEFUSE. But do you have links that works between Java-Php with the same implementation like this?

Comment: You need to use. Hex so the data can be seen, encryption is data, not strings. Base64 is useless for examining data bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the key, iv, input data and encrypted data in hex so they can be examined, encryption works with data, not strings.

> key: 546865426573745365637265744b6579
>   iv: 30313233343536373839303132333435
>   text: 48656c6c6f7720576f726c6421

and encryption in CBC mode with zero padding you should get encrypted:

> AE64AA4836D7251E03070C1647A4B531

but you don't, you get

> 4D70AFDDFFABFA1EF5CBF3730A4D3C1F

So it seems the encryption is bad.

See: [AES CALCULATOR](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=546865426573745365637265744b6579&iv=30313233343536373839303132333435&input=48656c6c6f7720576f726c6421&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=)

Comment: Thank you for the effort, i will change my code and will post my development.